# How to apply margin on DIV when printing with loop?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my Code:

```
<?php 
     $qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
     while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qr)):
?>

<div class="box">
    <p><?php echo $res[1]; ?></p>
    <img src="<?php echo $res[3]; ?>" width="100" /><br />
    <a href="<?php echo $res[4]; ?>">View Data Sheet</a>            
</div>

<?php 
    endwhile; 
?>
```

I want the output of the fetched record like this http://jsfiddle.net/CqYhE/3/

Please help me that how can I apply margin of 10px on both sides (left & right), only on the center div of each row when printing it with php loop.

Comment: how many boxes you have in one row?

Comment: And if you need help with using nth-child, you can visit http://codepen.io/RadLikeWhoa/full/cAJEo to see what you want

Comment: @PankitKapadia, 3 boxes in single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is your solution:**

*This will work for **N** divisions.*

```
<?php 
    $qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");

    $count = 1;
    $margin='';

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qr)):
        $count == 2 ? $margin='style="margin:0px 10px;"' : $margin = '';
        $count == 3 ? $count = 1 : $count++;
?>    

    <div class="box" <?php echo $margin; ?>>
        <p><?php echo $res[1]; ?></p>
        <img src="<?php echo $res[3]; ?>" width="100" /><br />
        <a href="<?php echo $res[4]; ?>">View Data Sheet</a>            
    </div>

<?php 
    endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors

```
#container .box{
    float: left;
    width:245px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0CC;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#container .box:first-child,
#container .box:last-child { margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;}
```

if you have Multiple Rows you will need to change you html to make it easy : See This **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owokov/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved with a CSS solution. If you forget about the left margin and just apply a right one you can then remove it from the last-child. Fewer lines of CSS so better performance.

```
.box{
    float: left;
    width:245px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0CC;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
}
.box:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```